# Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() wamp3x64 instantclient-basic-windows.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip php5.6

Tags: oracle, oci8, wamp3

I am using wamp3 64bit, installed native client 12_1x64  but still got same error. Also enable the extention php_oci8_12c.dll in php.ini file but no success

Can anyone help me out, using oracle 12 in 64 bit OS

Comment: Have you enabled the Oracle DLL's?

Comment: Did you restart apache after enabling OCI? Also, view a phpinfo page (just put `<?php phpinfo();` and nothing else in a page and view it) and does it show that OCI is enabled?

Comment: Restarted several time, oci is not showing in phpinfo page

Comment: @JayBlanchard how to enable it, i just copied it to wamp php ext directory, also tried with instant_client folder at c drive and defining path var but no luck